# How do I create an authenticated session in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

I have a situation where I'm using Credentials auth successfully, but I sometimes need to be able to simply create an authenticated session from inside a service using nothing but the user's email address. How can I do that? I suppose I'm looking for something similar in intent to `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()`, but I haven't found it.

Here's my thinking so far. Assuming I have to construct this myself, I see this inside `CredentialsAuthProvider.TryAuthenticate`:

```
if (authRepo.TryAuthenticate(userName, password, out userAuth))
{
    session.PopulateWith(userAuth);
    session.IsAuthenticated = true;
    session.UserAuthId = userAuth.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    session.ProviderOAuthAccess = authRepo.GetUserOAuthProviders(session.UserAuthId)
        .ConvertAll(x => (IOAuthTokens)x);

    return true;
}
```

That seems to imply that I can do what's inside the block myself via a `UserAuth` object from `IUserAuthRepository.GetUserAuthByUserName()`. I don't think this is enough though, since the session isn't saved here. Working backwards, I found that `TryAuthenticate` is called by Authenticate which then goes on to call `OnAuthenticated` where other things happen including saving the session. Can I resolve an instance of `CredentialsAuthProvider` and call OnAuthenticated myself?

Am I on the right track, or is this the completely wrong way of going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sometimes need to be able to simply create an authenticated session from inside a service using nothing but the user's email address. How can I do that? I suppose I'm looking for something similar in intent to FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()**

I think the simplest, most `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()` way I can think of is to modify the AuthUserSession within in your service. The code below will get the Session, set IsAuthenticated to true, set the email and save the Session.

```
public class SomeService : Service
{
    public String Any(SomeRequest request)
    {
        //not sure you need it, but you could put some code here to verify the email is allowed to authenticate
        //and if true run the code below
        var sess = this.SessionAs<AuthUserSession>();
        sess.IsAuthenticated = true;
        sess.Email = "test@email.com";
        this.SaveSession(sess);

        return "success";
    }
}
```

Comment: That technically works, but the session can't really be used for anything as it's almost completely empty other than the email address. I can populate that from `UserAuth`, but even then it's missing other things like `UserAuthId` that other classes expect to be there. I suppose I can populate that too, but there's also a cookie missing, `X-UAId`. It seems like I'm recoding the wheel here, which is what I was hoping I wouldn't have to do.

Comment: Well, if you're really trying to 'Authenticate' using only an email address your best bet might be to create a custom authentiation provider (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#custom-authentication-and-authorization).

Comment: Yeah, that looks like the route I'll need to go. Thanks.